# .NET String showing UTF-8 characters as \u0394

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, utf-8

The problem is that I receive a large response via a HttpWebResponse API request. From this response I extract and transfer this info to separate strings. This works fine as long as there are no accented characters or other non-alphabetical stuff. When I create a string with "é" for example, it is shown as U+00E9 instead of é.

I've searched the Internet for this for days now but I haven't found a simple solution yet. I've read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and I understand a bit what the UTF-8 format means, but I haven't got any clue about what should I do to display special characters in a String.

This is the code I use to grab the WebResponse:

```
 Public Function ExecuteApiRequest(url As String) As String
    Dim requestResult As String = ""
    global_oauth_timestamp = setTimeStamp()
    global_oauth_nonce = setNounce()

    Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"",oauth_nonce=""{1}"",oauth_token=""{2}"",oauth_signature=""{3}"",oauth_signature_method=""{4}"",oauth_timestamp=""{5}"""
    Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(global_oauth_timestamp))

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse

    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader  'ghfh,hrgnfgd
    Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.UserAgent = global_user_agent
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Timeout = -1
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)

    Try
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode)
        requestResult = streamReader.ReadLine
        request.Abort()
        streamReader.Close()
        streamReader = Nothing
        response.Close()
        response = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

    If requestResult.Contains("You are making requests too quickly.") Then
        MsgBox("TOO MANY REQUESTS")
    End If

    Return requestResult
End Function
```

As you can see the result is returned as a String, perhaps the problem starts there?

Comment: response.ContentEncoding is empty when I use it. You are right, I use UTF-8 as encoding but that's just guessing.

Comment: [`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: [U+00E9](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) is a representation of "é", typically used for discussion purposes. Where are you seeing that representation? Why is \u0394 in the title? (And, technically there are no UTF-8 characters. There are Unicode characters and UTF-8 is one of several encodings for that character set.)

Comment: @Tom Blodget: I see the \U00E9 representation in my vb form, where all the extracted info from the webresponse is displayed in deperate text boxes. I Also save to an ms access database and also there \U00E9 is used instead of é. \u0394 is in the title because I actually typed \u0394...
For example, I scrape the artist and track title from https://www.discogs.com/%CE%94-Skyway/release/4326017 this release: https://www.discogs.com/%CE%94-Skyway/release/4326017

The artists name is Δ Δ and when I copy/paste it, 2 signs are shown here instead of \u.....

Comment: But when I use the response of my API request and convert it to string, \u.... is used

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read everything from the response output stream into a byte array using the `stream.read()` function and then convert that byte array into UTF-8 using `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"Page scraping" gets you HTML.

Web API calls usually get you JSON (or XML—the X in AJAX used to mean XML). It seems that's what you've got because \u0394 is a possible way of expressing é in a string literal. (Another way is simply é.)

The documentation, if any, should help but the response Content-Type header would say `application/json`.

> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed
> ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8.
> …Note:  No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
> Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.
> —[RFC8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

(The older standard allows UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32—all easily distinguished, assuming JSON.)

Your `.ReadLine` is a bit strange but JSON is often created without line breaks so it makes sense in a way. However, I recommend `.ReadToEnd()`.

So, once you have JSON in requestResult, you need to deserialize it. The end result would be an instance of a class you define. (In C#, it could be a `dynamic` object.) You can easily [generate](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+to+class) classes from a JSON sample.

To serialize and deserialize JSON, Newtonsoft's [JSON.NET NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) is extremely common. Use `JsonConvert.Deserialize` to convert to your classes or `JObject.Parse` to get an object you can navigate through like this `JObject.Parse(requestResult)("results").First()("title")`.

Ultimately, you might prefer a comprehensive Web API client like [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/).